# Vue-MultiSelect Checkbox binding

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, multi-select, vue-multiselect

The data properties of the multi-select component does not update on change. Check-boxes doesn't update on the front-end.

**Expected Behavior: The check-boxes should get ticked, when clicked.**

Link to code: https://jsfiddle.net/bzqd19nt/3/

```
<div id="app">
  <multiselect 
    select-Label=""
    selected-Label=""
    deselect-Label=""
    v-model="value" 
    :options="options"
    :multiple="true"
    track-by="library"
    :custom-label="customLabel"
    :close-on-select="false"
    @select=onSelect($event)
    @remove=onRemove($event)
    >
    <span class="checkbox-label" slot="option" slot-scope="scope" @click.self="select(scope.option)">
    {{ scope.option.library }}
      <input class="test" type="checkbox" v-model="scope.option.checked" @focus.prevent/>

    </span>
  </multiselect>
  <pre>{{ value }}</pre>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
  },
  data: {
    value: [],
    options: [
      { language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vue.js', checked: false },
      { language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vue-Multiselect', checked: false },
      { language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vuelidate', checked: false }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    customLabel(option) {
      return `${option.library} - ${option.language}`;
    },
    onSelect(option) {
      console.log('Added');
      option.checked = true;
      console.log(`${option.library}  Clicked!! ${option.checked}`);
    },

    onRemove(option) {
      console.log('Removed');
      option.checked = false;
      console.log(`${option.library}  Removed!! ${option.checked}`);
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your code you call `onSelect` and try to change the `option` argument of this function inside the function:

```
option.checked = true;
```

This affects only the local variable `option` (the function argument). And doesn't affect objects in `options` array in the `data` of the Vue instance, the objects bound with checkboxes. That's why nothing happens when you click on an option in the list.

To fix it find the appropriate element in `options` array and change it:

```
let index = this.options.findIndex(item => item.library==option.library);
this.options[index].checked = true;
```

Here is the code snippet with fix:

```js
new Vue({
 components: {
   Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
 },
 data: {
   value: [],
   options: [
     { language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vue.js', checked: false },
      { language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vue-Multiselect', checked: false },
      { language: 'JavaScript', library: 'Vuelidate', checked: false }
    ]
 },
  methods: {
   customLabel (option) {
      return `${option.library} - ${option.language}`
    },
    onSelect (option) {
     console.log("Added");
      let index = this.options.findIndex(item => item.library==option.library);
      this.options[index].checked = true;
      console.log(option.library + "  Clicked!! " + option.checked);
    },
    
    onRemove (option) {
     console.log("Removed");
      let index = this.options.findIndex(item => item.library==option.library);
      this.options[index].checked = false;
      console.log(option.library + "  Removed!! " + option.checked);
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Avenir', sans-serif;
}

.checkbox-label {
  display: block;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.2/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.3/dist/vue-multiselect.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <multiselect 
    select-Label=""
    selected-Label=""
    deselect-Label=""
    v-model="value" 
    :options="options"
    :multiple="true"
    track-by="library"
    :custom-label="customLabel"
    :close-on-select="false"
    @select=onSelect($event)
    @remove=onRemove($event)
    >
    <span class="checkbox-label" slot="option" slot-scope="scope" @click.self="select(scope.option)">
    {{ scope.option.library }}
      <input class="test" type="checkbox" v-model="scope.option.checked" @focus.prevent/>
      
    </span>
  </multiselect>
  <pre>{{ value }}</pre>
</div>
```